# How to draw 2 nested rectangles using ONLY 4 vertices in the buffer in Webgl?

Tags: webgl

I know how to use a uniform variable to move the rectangle around, but I don't know how to make it smaller or bigger to fit one into the other. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
var vertices = 
    [
  vec2(0.0, 0.0 ),  
  vec2(0.4, 0),
  vec2(0, 0.4),
  vec2(0.4, 0.4)  
];

gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
gl.clearColor( 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0 );

var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
gl.useProgram( program );

// Create a buffer for the vertex shader in the GPU.
var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();

// Tell the GPU to expect data for this buffer
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId );

    // Send data into the buffer.   
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );   

// Set up the buffer for use
var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "myvPosition" );

// myvPosition (identified using vPosition) will correspond to 2 floats per vertex,
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );

// Enable use of the vertex buffer with myvPosition
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

// Get an index to each uniform variable in the GPU's shader      
var xIndex   = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "xAdjust" );
var yIndex   = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "yAdjust" );
var rIndex   = gl.getUniformLocation(  program, "red" );
var gIndex   = gl.getUniformLocation(  program, "green" );
var bIndex   = gl.getUniformLocation(  program, "blue" );

gl.uniform1f( xIndex, -0.25 );    // move to the left

gl.uniform1f( gIndex,  1.0 );


gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );  // note new place to put clear

render();

gl.uniform1f( xIndex, +0.25 );    // move to the right

gl.uniform1f( rIndex,  1.0 );

render();   
};

function render()  
{   
   gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4 );
 }
```

for example: I can change the value in the gl.uniform1f(xIndex, ) to move the rectangle along x axis

Comment: First show us your code how to move it and we might help you to scale/rotate it.

Comment: I added some codes for you to see. xIndex is a uniform variable declared in another file.

Comment: I will help you tomorrow, it is 1am here :)

Comment: ok, good night and remember to get back to me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time to learn about transformation matrix. There is a lot of math, but I will try to explain it as simple as possible.

Lets pick new square 1x1:

```
var vertices = 
    [
  vec2(0, 0),  
  vec2(1, 0),
  vec2(0, 1),
  vec2(1, 1)  
];
```

Now if you would like to move it to the left by 1 (as you did), you want to add 1 to [x] of all your vertices. This look simple. 
If you want to rotate it, it is much more complicated. Imagine your object would be from 50000 vertices and not just 4 => super complicated!

So people invented some procedure that is widely used. We create transformation matrix for each object we have. In 2D, matrix is 3x3. In 3D, matrix is 4x4.

How the matrix works? First you create vertices, then initalize matrix with

```
// js example
var model1M = mat3.create([
 1, 0, 0,
 0, 1, 0,
 0, 0, 1]);
```

Which means "no transformation done" yet. Then you translate, rotate, scale your object by operations with matrix. **Remember, transformation order is important!!**

```
move & rotate != rotate & move
```

Once you want to render, you send matrix to the shader.

```
// this is how you send 1 float value
gl.uniform1f( xIndex, -0.25 );    // move to the left

// this is how we send 3x3 matrix
var mvmi = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "modelViewMatrix" );
gl.uniformMatrix3fv(mvmi, false, model1M);
```

And in shader:

```
// you have to modify what is in vec4
gl_Position = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
```

and its done.

Problem is `mat3` doesnt exist in js. Math for transformations:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/2D_affine_transformation_matrix.svg

You need to implement all the math first. But easier is just download library for example http://glmatrix.net/ and include `gl-matrix-min.js`. Then follow documentation http://glmatrix.net/docs/2.2.0/symbols/mat3.html .

Simple cookbook:

```
var DEG_TO_RAD = 0.0174532925;

// create matrix, you dont have to type numbers in
var modelMatrix = mat3.create();

// move
mat3.translate(modelMatrix, modelMatrix, [-0.5, -0.5]);

// rotate by 45 degrees
mat3.rotate(modelMatrix, modelMatrix, 45*DEG_TO_RAD);

// make square smaller
mat3.scale(modelMatrix, modelMatrix, [0.4, 0.4]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Enity Black. You rocked :D